# Why does composite component "rendered" attribute throw an IllegalArgument Exception?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I create a composite component like this:

```
<cc:interface>        
    <cc:attribute name="value" 
                  required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="rendered"
                  displayName="True to render"
                  default="true" />
</cc:interface>
```

When I invoke this component, I get an IllegalArgumentException.  I can changed the **rendered** name to something else (like **doIt**)  and then it works.

Is the **rendered** attribute reserved somehow?  I want my composite component to look like "regular" JSF components.

This is with Mojarra.

Comment: In the future, you don't need to explicitly tag `[mojarra]` if the problem is not Mojarra specific. You would have exactly the same problem when you tried for example MyFaces. Just mentioning JSF impl/version in the question is sufficient.

Comment: I put Mojarra there because I thought it might be a Mojarra bug.  But point taken.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Composite components extend [`UINamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) which in turn extend [`UIComponentBase`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html) which in turn *already* definies the `id` and `rendered` attributes. You don't need to specify them yourself. Just remove the `<cc:attribute name="rendered">`. If you specify the `rendered` attribute on the composite component tag, then it'll be interpreted and applied on the composite component itself.

If you intend to render *specific* children of the composite, then better invent a different attribute name. For example, `renderSomeChild`.

Comment: When editing the component in the NetBeans 7.1 editor, it considers the **rendered** attribute to be an error when it is not defined by a **cc:attribute** element.  Is that a Netbeans bug?

Comment: Sorry, I have not really used Netbeans for more than 5 minutes. It works fine that way in Eclipse.

Comment: As much sense as you answer makes, it have the same problem in Eclipse: The "rendered" attribute of my own composition component is underlined and marked as an unknown element. JSF 2.1.24, Eclipse 3.7.2 with JBOSS JSF tools.